# How to run a Spring Boot program deployed on AWS

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

New to both AWS and Spring Boot. I have successfully deployed my spring boot application to an AWS server, as shown here:

[image: Build Successful message]

However, I do not know how to run the program now that it is on the server. Main method is straightforward:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
}
```

Do I need to implement a REST call just to run the main? How do I start this program remotely now that it is deployed?

Comment: You should probably look at building a .jar file e.g., with maven/gradel. Then you can run your app with java -jar yourapp.jar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can deploy a Spring BOOT WEB app to the Cloud by using [Elastic Beanstalk](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/). When you do so, you get an URL that you can use to access the application within a WEB Browser. For example, when I deploy a Spring BOOT app to AWS Elastic Beanstalk, I can view the URL in the Console:

[image]

To learn how to create a Spring BOOT Web app that can invoke AWS Services using the AWS SDK for Java V2 (for example, Amazon DynamoDB) and deploy it to the Cloud, see:

[Creating your first AWS Java web application](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/javav2/usecases/creating_first_project)

This app uses [Thymeleaf](https://www.thymeleaf.org/) to define the UI for the app. However, if you do not have a UI, only controllers, you can still deploy the same way and then send a GET/POST requests to the Spring Controllers.

Comment: My application does not have a UI - I just want the service to run like when I hit run in my IDE. Will this method work for that?

Comment: Yes - you can still deploy the same way and then send Rest requests to the Controllers - such as a GET request

Comment: Ok so I do need a Rest call, theres not an equivalent of a "java -jar" call for aws?

Comment: You deploy the App to the Cloud (it does not matter if you have a UI or not). If you do not have a UI, you can still send Restful requests that will hit the controllers defined in your Spring Controller class.  For example, you can use a tool like Postman to send a  GET request.